# How can i get arrays from a function in a for loop with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, function, matlab, for-loop

I'm new to Python and I would like to write a function that, given n inputs, returns m outputs.
I can do this in Matlab, with a function like:

`[a,b,c,d] = my_function(x,y,z,h)`

where `(x,y,z,h)` are multidimensional arrays.

In particular, having:

```
A=np.zeros((3,150,150))
B=np.zeros((3,150,150))
C=np.zeros((3,150,150))
D=np.zeros((3,150,150))
p=zero(3,1)
```

and given the for loop:

```
x.shape=(1540,1838)
step=10
jj=0
for j in range(0,1838,step):
     jj=jj+1 #tot= 184

     ii=0
     for i in range(0,1540,step):
         ii=ii+1 #total 154
         pos=x(i,j)
```

executing now, within the for loop, my_function, I get the output:

```
a=A(:,ii,jj)
b=B(:,:,ii,jj)
c=C(:,:,ii,jj)
d=D(:,ii,jj)
```

Ho can I write the same function in Python style?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def my function(x, y, z, h):
  # do some compute stuff
  # ...
  return a, b, c, d
```

Comment: Is it correct write a=A(:,ii,jj) as a=A.reshape(A[:,ii,jj]) in python? I ask you 'cause i'm new in python

Comment: For the reshaping, that's a different question and you'd need to explain a bit more concisely what you want to achieve

Comment: I don't know if reshape is right for my request.
How can i write a=A(:,ii,jj) in python style from Matlab style (as i wrote in my question)?

Comment: This should just be `a = A[:, ii, jj]` then

Comment: I tried, but i received: IndexError: index 150 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 150

Comment: Matlab indices start at 1, right? Because python indices start at 0...

Comment: Yes, but i get the same error

Comment: I wrote: A[:,1,2]=A[:,ii,jj] (take all the values of the second and third column and replace them progressively, with each value ii and jj of the for loop).

i get: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,) into shape (3,)